# Convergence in distribution of a normalized Poisson distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Show using the **central limit theorem** that $\frac{X_n-n}{n^{1/2}}\rightarrow Z$ where $Z$ is standard normally distributed and $X_n$ is $Poisson(n)$ distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with the fact that Poisson distributions are stable under addition? In other words $Poisson(a)+Poisson(b)=Poisson(a+b)$ for two independent $Poisson(a),Poisson(b)$ distributions, where equality is in distribution. This gives $Poisson(n)=Poisson(1)+\cdots+Poisson(1)$.

Is it obvious now how to apply the central limit theorem?

Comment: Shame on me, was not familiar with the fact (of forgot it incompletely), yes not it is clear how to apply the CLT, thanks!

Comment: @SergeyZykov: it's an easy exercise to prove, even easier to see from the characteristic function for the Poisson distribution.